# Swapping different bits between 2 integers - C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, swap

i need help.

I need to solve this problem of swapping 2 different bits between 2 different integers.

Examlpe (Swap bit *3* of (101) with bit *2* of (100))

Would result to *(001)* & *(110)*

My trial

```
void swap(unsigned int numberA, unsigned int numberB, int bitPositionA, int bitPositionB)
{
    unsigned int aShift = 1 << bitPositionA, bShift = 1 << bitPositionB;
    unsigned int bitA = numberA & aShift;
    unsigned int bitB = numberB & bShift;


    numberB &= ~bShift; // Set the bit to `0`
    numberB |= bitA;    // Set to the actual bit value

    numberA &= ~aShift; // Set the bit to `0`
    numberA |= bitB;    // Set to the actual bit value

    printf("Number[1] => %d Number => %d",numberA,numberB);
}
```

Wrong output of `swap(5,4,3,2)` -> `Number[1] => 5 Number => 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're forgetting that bits, like arrays, are numbered starting from **zero**, not **one**.

   Replace your call to `swap` with:

   ```
   swap(5, 4, 2, 1);
   ```
2. The code that ORs in the new bits does not move them into the bit location that they're supposed to go into in the new number. They remain at the bit location that they were pulled out of in the source number.

   ```
   numberB &= ~bShift; // Set the bit to `0`
   if(bitA)
       bitA = 1 << bitPositionB;
   numberB |= bitA;    // Set to the actual bit value

   numberA &= ~aShift; // Set the bit to `0`
   if(bitB)
       bitB = 1 << bitPositionA;
   numberA |= bitB;    // Set to the actual bit value
   ```

Comment: Hello @Govind Parmar, excuse me but that results into `Number[1] => 1 Number[2] => 4` not the required result.

Comment: @HassanA.El-Seoudy You're right; I just updated my answer

Comment: @HassanA.El-Seoudy No problem, if you are satisfied with my answer feel free to accept it by clicking the check mark!

Answer (score 0):

```
void swap(unsigned int numberA, unsigned int numberB, int bitPositionA, int bitPositionB)
{
    unsigned int aShift = 1 << bitPositionA-1, bShift = 1 << bitPositionB-1;
    unsigned int bitA = numberA & aShift;
    unsigned int bitB = numberB & bShift;


    numberB &= ~bShift; // Set the bit to `0`
    numberB |= bitA >> (bitPositionB-1);    // Set to the actual bit value

    numberA &= ~aShift; // Set the bit to `0`
    numberA |= bitB >> (bitPositionA-1);    // Set to the actual bit value

    printf("Number[1] => %02X Number => %02X \n",numberA,numberB);
}
```